# Component exposed from @expo/vector-icons cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

[image]

VS code give me the above alert, when I am using the AntDesign exposed from "expo/vector-icons".

```
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";

export type Icon = {
  name: "home" | "crafts";
};

export function Icon({ name }: Icon) {
  return (
    <AntDesign
      size={24}
      name={(() => {
        switch (name) {
          case "crafts":
            return "appstore-o";
          case "home":
          default:
            return "home";
        }
      })()}
      color="black"
    />
  );
}
```

I think I am following the practice shared by the official document, isn't it?
Need help.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @Veita No not yet. I did some researching online but found this issue is not common. I'm wondering if this is a problem in some versions of expo only. Let me know if you have some clues.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by upgrading `@types/react` to the latest release.

Basically, I had several packages depending on `@types/react`, and I also had `@types/react` installed as a dev dependency in my app's package.json.

Presumably the version used by a dependency was different from my installed version, and this caused the IDE error.

This Github issue was pretty helpful:  https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/59765